# NSTimer not running selector?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I have the following two statements which in essence should do exactly the same thing as far as I understand:

```
//[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideSuccessImageFromAllScreen:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[self performSelector:@selector(hideSuccessImageFromAllScreen:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

followed by

```
-(void)hideSuccessImageFromAllScreen:(NSTimer *)timer{...
```

The perform selector method runs just fine and the selector is executed. However, if I uncomment the first line and comment out the second one the selector never fires. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to start the timer manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either have to start the timer manually, or use `+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]`, which will automatically start it for you:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                              selector:@selector(hideSuccessImageFromAllScreen:)
                              userInfo:nil
                               repeats:NO];
```